# Sverchok || Make a switch stick to its position for X frames (i.e create a trigger/buffer)

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, sverchok

(Maybe the title is not accurate)
Hi,

I'm trying to find a way to create a kind of buffer in sverchok, for a animation project. With the timeline playing in Blender, once a event occurs (every 25 frames for example), I need a node to trigger for a given number of frames, during which a group of nodes will randomly select some meshes and perform simple deformations on those.

I use a switch to "trigger" the selection + deformation process. But this switch goes back to it's position as soon a the frame changes. So my selection only holds for 1frame, and the mesh deformations are made on a 1 frame long basis.

**Is it possible to make it "hold" its position ? Is there any other way to achieve this ?**

A quick example to illustrate what kind of thing I'm trying to achieve : you have 30 meshes in the viewport, you hit play in the timeline, and every 25 frames you need 5 randomly selected meshes to rotate then come back to it's original position for a 10 frames duration of animation.
So :

- Frame 0-25 nothing happens,
- Frame 25-35 there's 5 meshes that rotates and come back to their original position,
- Frame 35-50 nothing happens etcetc.

I hope someone has a solution, I've searched a long time for this, and I really need to find a way to do this...
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you right, you can get it with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm, and I've learned a lot too : making the seed and the modulo "counter" synchronised for the same period of time allowed me to get rid of the switch. Honestly, I would have not guessed that on my own. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome